# Move the label to the left side of the checkbox using css only

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

I have following code:

```
<div>
 <span>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>I want this to be on the left side</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

And I would like to move the label to the left side of the checkbox using css styles only, as I cannot change the HTML file because it is autogenerated.
Any ideas please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to use the flexbox order property.

```css
.flex-control {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-control input {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span class="flex-control">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>I want this to be on the left side</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

display:flex and ordering help always solve such problems

```css
span {
  display:flex;
}

label {
  order:1;
}

input {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>
   <input type="checkbox">
  <label>I want this to be on the left side</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that **without** setting the `order`

```css
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>I want this to be on the left side</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *old* float is also good here:

```css
span {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
label {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>I want this to be on the left side</label>
 </span>
</div>
```